# Simulator of Xcode Projects is blank

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.4

as mentioned above, during one of the courses I am taking, when I run my project, the simulator opens the app, which appears to be blank. 
I already reviewed many posts from people who had the same problem of mine and I tried unsuccessfully their solutions.

The solutions I reviewed are:
- Erase all content of the simulator
- Changed the type of simulator (from iPhone 8 plus to iPhone 7 plus)
- Making sure I had the right settings on the Info.plist
- Build different times the program from scratch as a new one.
 And probably others I don't even remember.

I attach my files, as well as the page that opens right when my Simulator launches the application. ( **the last screenshot** )

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]
[image: Forth]
[image: Fifth]
Here is the error log

```
2018-06-18 22:52:29.685489+0200 Bullseye[2247:47563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Bullseye.ViewController 0x7fc0df70bf90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numValue.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010625e1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102665031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010625e0b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000102086b47 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010309cec0 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010338ae8a -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106200e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103389834 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001030a40d7 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001030a4a04 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001030a4d21 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001030a5574 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102f73123 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000102f73834 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000102f865cc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102efa3da -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4739
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102eff5cb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1677
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001032c1f7e __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000103694a39 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001032c1bba -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001032c23db -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000103c33614 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 299
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103c334ae -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010391775d __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000103b124b7 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000103917627 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001036940e0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000102efdeac -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001034d0bcb -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010828d2f3 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108295cfa __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001073c27ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001073c7db8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001082c1470 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001082c112e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001082c168e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106200bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061e54af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061e4a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061e430b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108b56a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    41  UIKit                               0x0000000102f01057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    42  Bullseye                            0x0000000101d5bad7 main + 55
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010743f955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole error log?

Comment: @VasilGarov I added to the main post the whole error log. It must be said that the last screenshot pops up only when I click on the screen.

Comment: Okay, where are you using 'numValue'?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have a bad connection in your outlets. Review them. If you have them changed in the view controller, you still need to update them in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

the simulator is blank because your app is crashing. Check your storyboard outlet connections to make ensure they are all connected. Open the connections inspector and look out for any broken connections. If your connections are right the circles in your view controller should be filled (see image below)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is weird.. as you can see from the screenshot I attached in my main post the circles are not filled. But right now they are filled.

Comment: Sometimes that happens with Xcode, but is the issue fixed now?

Comment: Definitely not, the same error strikes again. I am attaching to my main post my menu from the connection inspector hoping this may help.